# Magento - One page checkout - Remove right column and resize main column to full size

Tags: magento, checkout

I want to resize the one page checkout site to the full size of the window. Now the right column is there, but i can´t find to remove it an resize the main column to the full size.

I have edited checkout.xml like i do it for the other sites, but it dont´t help. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other module that override the checkout.xml?

Do a simple search in the layout folder for "Checkout", also always clear chace and re-index the magento.

Comment: I have no other modules. The cache is disabled and i remove the hole cache. I use the newest version from magento.